# Isolate two parts of string in php

Tags: php, string, split

How can I isolate the numbers and words in a string?

So I have something like this:

```
11111111-test-title
```

I want to have:

```
11111111
```

...in one string and:

```
test-title
```

...in another.

Thanks :)

Comment: Following what rule? Is it always going to be numbers and words? What about the connecting dash between the number and the words? How large will the numbers be? These kinds of questions need *lots* of details for a good answer

Comment: ok, yeah I forgot to mention those. at the start there will always be numbers, and then after there could be many different amounts of words, so it could be 3939393-word-word2-word3     or just 393993-word  etc, $parts = explode('-', $string, 2); would work but how would i isolate $parts[0]; from the others, and then merge all the other parts?

Comment: which "other" parts? After performing that code you have 2 items size array (or one, if there was no any `-` in the string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$parts = explode('-', $string, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list](http://php.net/list) and [explode](http://php.net/explode):

```
list($number, $text) = explode('-', $input, 2);
```

Or simply `explode` to get an array. The third argument tells it to separate it in a maximum of two parts, stopping after the first `-`.